# No Class Def Found Eclipse Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to read wave file into a double array. The problem is that I have included JRE System library which contains the class definition for AudioSystem.class that I am using but I get the No Class Def Found Excepition and I have tried checking it in order and export tab and also changing the order of the src and gen folder and also kept JRE System Library in the top. Nothing Works. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we cant reference JRE system lib in our android project